# What's the purpose of using '[' & ']' in a Swift statement?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I found the following piece of code in a Swift demo app:

```
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: true)]
```

I know the Objective-C '[...]' syntax.

But why use it in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

That is creating an array (with just one element in this case).

Note the plural in the field name.